# How to remove unnecessary elements in the HTML document head

Tags: wp-head, customization

Is there a plugin or something that can help me out with deleting unnecessary elements in my code?

I am in charge of fixing a WordPress site and have been asked to remove the following elements that are not necessary, for example, I don't have any pagination in my pages but in my code there is still:

- `<link rel='prev' title='Barcelona' href='http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/barcelona/' />`
- `<link rel='next' title='Frequently Asked Questions'
  href='http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/frequently-asked-questions/'
  />`

Again with the RSS feed:

- `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Creative Square
  Summer Camp RSS2 Feed"
  href="http://www.creativesquaresummercamp.com/feed/" />`

How can I clean up the code / delete unnecessary elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are default settings fron WordPress.
This was set via `wp-includes/default_filters.php` or the feed inside your theme.

Check the theme, `functions.php` for 
`add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );`
and remove it.

Add this via plugin or `functions.php` in your theme for remove the different defaults, hints and small description is on the source.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 ); // Display the links to the extra feeds such as category feeds
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 ); // Display the links to the general feeds: Post and Comment Feed
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rsd_link' ); // Display the link to the Really Simple Discovery service endpoint, EditURI link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link' ); // Display the link to the Windows Live Writer manifest file.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'index_rel_link'); // index link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // prev link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0 ); // start link
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 ); // Display relational links for the posts adjacent to the current post.
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_generator' ); // Display the XHTML generator that is generated on the wp_head hook, WP version
```

Comment: ok, where exactly i put this lines in the function.php? at the bottom it's fine? Otherwise which plugin you mean to insert these lines of code? Thanks

Comment: Write a custom plugin for your install. Or on the end of the functions.php of the theme.

Comment: Preferably in a plugin ([very easy to get started](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Creating_a_Plugin)) so you don't need to manually port any code over when switching themes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from the theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
```

… and add this to the file:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head' );
```