# Remove tags from wordpress head

Tags: html, wp-head

I don't know when or why but this tags are inserted on my wordpress head automatically and they are adding style that disturb my layout:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.2">

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

How can I remove it? It is annoying!
Actually the generator is the minor of my problems. Look at all the things that are there:
[image]

The reason why I added wp-head on the first place was because I wanted to use a SEO plugin, but this gets inyected even without that plugin enabled.

Comment: Search the site. I am sure this has been answered.

Comment: yes, but how to write the question? I did search but didn't find what I wanted. This seems to be a new issue, I didn't experience it a year ago

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable all plugins and use the default theme?

Comment: happens without the plugins, the default theme I don't know I just added the wp head with an include on my <head> tag. There is nothing strange...

Comment: [see this answer.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72823/4771)

Comment: @Milo It didn't work... I have all my plugins disabled and my theme is done by me, and the only thing that could be injecting it is wp-head.... It must be something from the core? But why does the core inject js and css on my theme? I don't understand it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe a filter on `the_generator` will do it.

```
add_filter( 
  'the_generator', 
  '__return_empty_string',
  PHP_INT_MAX
);
```

Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string. 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2956

Comment: this removed the generator but I want to know how to remove every undesired tags and, if possible, how did those get there,

Comment: The idea is the same. Find the hook and callback and either remove the callback or return an empty string. Some are added by Core, others by themes or plugins. ***You*** have to do that research yourself. Find a utility similar to `grep` and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you want to remove is added in [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L209). Look in that file to see where they are added. The two that are adding css and js are the emoji support scripts:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

To remove them, use the following in addition to the code which removes all the other bits [like in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72822/how-to-remove-unnecessary-elements-in-the-html-document-head/72823#72823):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

The other bits are for the admin toolbar when you're logged in. You can remove those by just unchecking admin toolbar in your user profile, or you can remove it entirely with:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```